# Can you query a Sql Server View with PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

So I know that you can query a table using PHP as so:

```
   $projectmanager=DB::table('Table_name')->distinct()->select('Table_Column')->get();
```

I want to know if you can do the same type of thing with a SQL Server View. I have tried the following:

```
$view=DB::view('View_Name')->select('View_Column')->get();
```

But I get the following error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection' does not have a method 'view'

Comment: What happens when you try querying the view as a table ?

Comment: It returns the error above ^

Comment: Just to make it clear, when you do `DB::table('View_Name')->select('View_Column')->get();` you get the error about the method `view` being nonexistent? A view is basically a table made of other tables. What @Maximus2012 wanted to point out is that you should use the method `DB::table` and not `DB::view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Laravel by chance?  Whatever the framework, you are calling a method DB::view that doesn't exist, so some class magic fails.

To answer question, yes.  To PHP they are seen the same as a regular table, treat it as such for querying (though you cannot manually update them of course).

```
$projectmanager=DB::table('View_name')->distinct()->select('View_column')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Laravel. Thank you for your answer, that seems really obvious and I should have found that answer somewhere else, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you.